# how to delete a panel and a window with python curses

Tags: python, curses

the documentation does not really mention how to delete a window or a panel;

the c api of curses has `delwin` and `del_panel` functions, but neither is available in the python api; does this mean the correct way of deleting a window in python is to simply unlink all references to it and let it be garbage collected? does the same apply to a panel?

---

the only place i found `del_panel` is called in the python `curses.panel` module is in the deallocator:

```
static void
PyCursesPanel_Dealloc(PyCursesPanelObject *po)
{
    PyObject *obj = (PyObject *) panel_userptr(po->pan);
    if (obj) {
        (void)set_panel_userptr(po->pan, NULL);
        Py_DECREF(obj);
    }
    (void)del_panel(po->pan);
    if (po->wo != NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(po->wo);
        remove_lop(po);
    }
    PyObject_DEL(po);
}
```

Comment: "Window"? "Panel"? What are you referring to, the console window?

Comment: @connectyourcharger no, the curses window and panel;

Comment: From the quoted fragment, it seems that the developer who made the Python script decided that the details of cleanup were too interdependent to provide low-level calls for each step.